# Angular 5 show Environment and app version on UI

Tags: angular

Trying to show environment of my angular app in the UI, for example test, dev, prod (i have separate test-env.ts, prod-ev.ts, dev-test.ts), is there a specific approach to achieve this, i want to to show the app version also next to the environment(not CLI version) based on deployment , for example i will start with V1.0 i want to automatically increment it to V1.1 if a deployment is made.

How to display environment when the app starts, i tried the following, but how determine different environments?

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log(isDevMode());
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add the name you want to display (i.e. `test`, `prod` etc) into the environment files, and access them from there

Comment: @user184994 Thanks, how to add backend services version also, i'm using AWS for the services, can a lambda function track the s3 version of services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to store it in a variable in environment.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

......


  constructor() { }

  public getEnvironmentVariableValue(): string | Object> {
    return `My environment variable: ${environment.myVersionVariable}';
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that works and marked it as solution  I'm looking now to display my AWS services version also, do you have a suggestion like showing version Id of S3 or ECS cluster? What is a logical method to update the number of version on deploys